# Using htmlspecialchars with foreach loops

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I an edit in my Opencart code, however after looking at a tutorial on foreach loops many highlight the importance of using htmlspecialchars to prevent injections.

Do I need to use it on the following code?

```
<?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>]]>
    <?php if ($total['title'] == "First Class") { $total['text'] = "Delivery"; } ?>
    <?php if ($total['title'] == "48Hr Courier") { $total['text'] = "Delivery"; } ?>
    <?php if ($total['title'] == "24Hr Courier") { $total['text'] = "Delivery"; } ?>
```

I see real_escape_string is another security feature used

Comment: no, you don't.  but i am basing that answer on a few informed assumptions I'm making about the context here.

Comment: You don't have to use `htmlspecialchars` in Opencart, as it runs every user input through `htmlspecialchars`, but only if you used Opencart's Request class to retrieve those inputs. To output actual HTML code, you have to un-escape the escaped HTML code using `htmlspecialchars_decode`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <search position="after"><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>]]></search>
```

this is not right xml....
You can use php librari simpleXml for create valid xml file, and `<![CDATA['sting '>o astea a'vyanmy'<>]]>` in this CDATA instruction, symbols not interpriter as special chars.

Comment: You probably don't understand what a vQmod xml file is for or how it's constructed

Comment: please read wikipedia or standard, an read old question when I write my answer http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35508275/revisions

Comment: yes i read the original question.  do you know anything about vqmod?